# Remove vertical scrollbars without additional element wrapping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been searching for a way to remove the scrollbars on a page while still allowing scrolling, but I've found that the general consensus is that you'd need to add additional elements that wrap your existing content.

Maybe I'm missing something. **Is there any way, using CSS and JS, to remove the vertical scrollbars while still allowing scrolling without adding additional elements around my content?**

The reason I ask is because I'm hoping to implement it into a jQuery plugin that effectively hides the scrollbars in favor of the plugins functionality, and I'd rather not wrap the plugin-user's page with additional elements for the sake of conflicting with their styling.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your content? Have any code you can share?

Comment: Well, since I don't have any code that works as described above, I'd essentially be showing you a static page with dummy paragraphs.

Comment: In Webkit ones (Chrome, Safari, Opera) you can do `body::-webkit-scrollbar { display :none }` : http://jsfiddle.net/QVyvs/2/, but I am not sure if there's equivalent in other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there isn't. Browsers don't support it. Facebook and other sites that implemented their own scrollbar functionality replacing the browser's use a technique to push the browser provided scrollbar out of the visible container and render their own scrollbar to be visible.